# Where can I find luxury goods advertisements for my website?

Tags: advertising

I'm running business directory for tourist attractions, and I would like to fill some empty blocks with useful advertisements like flight operators, car retailers, luxury goods etc.

We have tried Google AdSense but it's full of cheap, pointless and irrelevant advertisement that would make our website look cheap and bad.

So I'm curious is there any centralised resources for luxury goods and services?

Comment: Do you need more information on this topic or have you found the answer?

Comment: I'm open for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CJ.com yet? They're one of the more-established affiliate networks and I can see plenty of advertisers of luxury goods on there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your region falls within one of theirs but check out http://www.giltcity.com/ which is sort of a GroupOn for luxury businesses

Comment: It is not really what I'm looking for. I need something like affiliate program for luxury goods and services. Or at least not fat burning pills and online games, as most adverts network are flooded with such content.